# How to show additional option for size, brand in magento admin panel order description page

Tags: magento

I am importing some order using programmatically but i have a problem that how to show the additional attribute like size , brand etc after product name in the "Items Ordered" help me out

i have search a lot for this but not find the appropriate answer.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-create-customer-and-order-in-magento-with-full-blown-one-page-checkout-process-under-the-hood/

actually i have these information about product :

Array
(
    [pr_id] => 30250
    [sku_id] => 10086663
    [dmn] => (blank)
    [sector] => (blank)
    [cat] => (blank)
    [brnd] => Mimi Holliday 
    [supp] => Damaris Ltd
    [desc] => Black lace plunge bra with silk 
    [clr] => Black
    [size] => 32B
    [st] => Shipped
    [cn_cause] => 
    [ret_cause] => 
    [sl_amt] => 16.99
    [l_s_ex_vt] => 14.46
    [l_s_ex_vt_a_vh] => 14.46
    [l_p_ex_vt] => 6.87
    [l_cpn] => 0
    [l_shp_cst] => 1.63
    [mg_b_ds] => 7.59
    [mg_b_ds_prct] => 0.52489626556017
    [mg_a_ds] => 7.59
    [mg_a_ds_prct] => 0.52489626556017
)

Here size and brand is displayed i want to show them.

Comment: No screenshot visible

Comment: hello sir please give me answer

Comment: Do you want to convert product attribute to quote item and order item ?